# sed replace a line if prior line match pattern

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

I'd like to know how I could replace a line that contains a pattern but only if the prior line has another pattern using sed. I have a text file that contains the following:

```
Property: ONE
Value: some_value
Property: TWO
Value: some_value
Property: THREE
Value: some_other_value
```

So I want to find a line containing **some_value** and replace the entire line with another line or just update the value but only if the property line contains word **ONE**. The end result would looks like so

```
Property: ONE
Value: replaced_value
Property: TWO
Value: some_value
Property: THREE
Value: some_other_value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed '/Property: ONE/{n;s/Value:.*/Value: replaced_value/}' file
```

Once the pattern `Property: ONE` is found, I read the next line into the pattern buffer using the `n` command and substitute the value using the `s` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=": "} p {
   $2 = "replaced_value"
}
{
   p = ($0 ~ /^Property: *ONE/ ? 1 : 0)
} 1' file

Property: ONE
Value: replaced_value
Property: TWO
Value: some_value
Property: THREE
Value: some_other_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk 'p~/Property: ONE/{$NF="replaced_value"} {p=$0; print}' file
Property: ONE
Value: replaced_value
Property: TWO
Value: some_value
Property: THREE
Value: some_other_value
```